# Angular tree with advanced templates (tree within tree)

Tags: angularjs, tree

I'm trying to solve a problem, which is shown in "advanced" template. Whole tree works just fine except "advanced" template. It is supposed to show trees within trees. Any ideas how to make this template work with provided example JSON "mainBody"?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6ku6mr1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var app = angular.module("Application",[]);

        app.controller("treeCtrl",function ($scope){
            $scope.mainBody =
            {
                tpl: 'body',
                tpls:
                [
                    {
                        tpl: 'simple_a',
                        tpls:[],
                    },

                    {
                        tpl: 'body',
                        tpls:[
                            {
                                tpl: 'simple_b',
                                tpls:[],
                            },                          
                        ],
                    },

                    {
                        tpl: 'simple_b',
                        tpls:[],
                    },
                    {
                        tpl: 'advanced',
                        tpls_a:
                        {
                            tpl: 'body',
                            tpls:
                            [
                                {
                                    tpl: 'simple_b',
                                    tpls:[],

                                },                              

                                {
                                    tpl: 'simple_a',
                                    tpls:[],
                                },                              
                            ]
                        },
                        tpls_b:
                        {
                            tpl: 'body',
                            tpls:[]
                        },
                    },

                ]
            }

        });


    </script>   

</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="Application" ng-controller="treeCtrl">

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="body.html">
            <li ng-repeat="(key,currentTpl) in currentTpl.tpls" 
                ng-include="currentTpl.tpl + '.html'" 
                onload="parent=$parent.$parent.$parent"></li> 
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="advanced.html">
            <div>
                advanced template
            </div>

            <div ng-if="currentTpl.tpls_a" 
                ng-include="currentTpl.tpls_a.tpl + '.html'"  
                onload="currentTpl=currentTpl.tpls_a"></div>

            <div ng-if="currentTpl.tpls_b" 
                ng-include="currentTpl.tpls_b.tpl + '.html'"  
                onload="currentTpl=currentTpl.tpls_b"></div>
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="simple_a.html">
            <div>
                simple template A
            </div>      
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="simple_b.html">
            <div>
                simple template B
            </div>      
        </script>



            <div ng-include="mainBody.tpl + '.html'"  
            onload="currentTpl=mainBody"></div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: ok, I've found that the reason is scope of currentTpl, so the question now is how to pass "currentTpl.tpls_a" and "currentTpl.tpls_b" to new scope

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/o73a67ro/ doesn't work eighter

Answer (score 0):

With help of my workmate I've found solution, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/cz7rm7c6/

```
    app.directive('leaf', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'leaf.html',
        scope: {
            currentTpl: '=tpl'
        }
      };
    });
```